# getting exception while checking for valid username and password in sqlite

Tags: android

I'm trying to check for a valid user. But I'm getting the following `Exception`:

```
no such column: ABC(Code 1):, while compiling: SELECT _id, username, password 
FROM MyTable1 WHERE username=ABC
```

The code is as follows:

```
public int checkUser(String userName, String password) {
    int check = -1;
    int id = 2;
    String psword = new String();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, allColumns, COLUMN_USER_NAME + "=" + userName, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.v(TAG, "After CURSOR!!");
    psword = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PASSWORD));
    Log.v(TAG, "pasword: " + psword);
    if (psword.equals(password)) {
        check = 1;
    }
    return check;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?? Please help

Comment: did you change your code

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If username is varchar/text type  then

```
 Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, allColumns, COLUMN_USER_NAME
            + "=" + '"+userName+"', null, null, null, null);
```

This is sample login function

```
 public boolean checkUser(String username, String password) throws SQLException
    {
     String whereClause = " USERNAME =  '"+userName+"' "; 

    try {
        open();// dbopen
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, allColumns,whereClause, null, null, null, null);
      }catch(Exception e){
            }
 }
```

**or**

```
public boolean checkUser(String username, String password) throws SQLException
    {
      Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE username=? AND password=?", new String[]{username,password});
        if (mCursor != null) {
          if(mCursor.getCount() > 0)
             {
            return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
        }
```

Comment: Name type is text. Its SQLite db.

Comment: so username parameter will be in single qoute

Comment: I am expecting up voting on my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should add quotes around userName. You want the rows that match the string value "ABC" or 'ABC' I don't remember which quotes. If you don't put quotes you are matching with the column named ABC.

And you should use prepares statements instead. That would avoid you many problems.